# Mongo service not restart after Oplog Implementation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I added below code in mongod.conf file for oplog implementation

```
replication:
           replSetName:rs0
            oplogSizeMB:100
           master:true
```

After this I restart mongod service but error is coming.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet of `/var/log/mongo/mongod.log` (or wherever mongod logs are)?

Comment: `total 1.4G
drwxr-xr-x   2 mongod mongod   23 Feb  2 02:44 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root   root   4.0K Feb 12 13:51 ..
-rw-r-----   1 mongod mongod 1.4G Feb 12 13:49 mongod.log`

Comment: problem is resolved by updating mongodb in 3.4 but now I am not able to connect mongo with oplog